# Find the Expectation of $2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac {(y_i-\alpha)^2-\beta ^2}{(\beta^2+(y_i-\alpha)^2)^2}$ for $y_i$ i.i.d. Cauchy$(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Find the Expectation of $$2\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {(y_i-\alpha)^2-\beta ^2}{(\beta^2+(y_i-\alpha)^2)^2}$$ given $y_1,y_2...$ iid ~Cauchy$(\alpha,\beta)$ with pdf $(-\infty < y<\infty , \beta>0)$:

$$f(y;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\beta}{\pi\{\beta^2+(y-\alpha)^2\}}$$

P.S. the answer is $-n/2\beta^2$.

I can find $$\bar y=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y\beta}{\pi\{\beta^2+(y-\alpha)^2\}}$$

I tried putting the expectation inside the sum, but the $E(y_i)=y_i$ if I understand correctly, and it will simply remain the same.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Note that $\alpha, \beta$ are location scale parameter respectively. If $Z\sim\text{Cauchy}(0,1)$, then $Y=\beta Z+\alpha\sim\text{Cauchy}(\alpha,\beta)$. So the summand can be simplified as $\displaystyle \frac {Z^2-1}{Z^2+1}=1-\frac{2}{Z^2+1}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E\frac {(Y_1-\alpha)^2-\beta ^2}{(\beta^2+(Y_1-\alpha)^2)^2}&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {(y_1-\alpha)^2-\beta ^2}{(\beta^2+(y_1-\alpha)^2)^2}f(y_1)dy_1\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {(y_1-\alpha)^2-\beta ^2}{(\beta^2+(y_1-\alpha)^2)^2}\frac{\beta/\pi}{\beta^2+(y-\alpha)^2}dy_1\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi\beta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^3}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi\beta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {4-4x^2}{4(x^2+1)^3}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi\beta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {x^4+2x^4+1-x^4-6x^2+3}{4(x^2+1)^3}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi\beta^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {(x^2+1)^2-x^4-6x^2+3}{4(x^2+1)^3}dx\\
...&=-\frac{1}{\pi\beta^2}\times \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align}